# Как вывести предпоследний элемент массива twig ? Opencart

Tags: массивы, opencart, twig, breadcrumbs

Необходимо чтобы данная инструкция выполнялась только для предпоследнего элемента массива. Как в twig правильно задать условие?

```html
{% for breadcrumb in breadcrumbs %}
    <li><a href="{{ breadcrumb.href }}">{{ breadcrumb.text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable без лишних слов. Можно ещё, конечно, попробовать `breadcrumbs[breadcrumbs |length - 2]`

Comment: спасибо за ответ, методом полного незнания было прописано так {% if key +2 == breadcrumbs|length %} это законно?)

Comment: Законно. Можно ещё попробовать `{% for key, breadcrumb in breadcrumbs if (key + 2) == breadcrumbs|length %}`

Answer (score -1):

```
<!-- 1 вариант -->
{% for breadcrumb in breadcrumbs|slice(-2,1) %}
<li><a href="{{ breadcrumb.href }}">{{ breadcrumb.text }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}


<!-- 2 вариант -->
{% set breadcrumb = breadcrumbs|slice(-2,1)|first %}
<li><a href="{{ breadcrumb.href }}">{{ breadcrumb.text }}</a></li>
```